# error in verilog "varible cannot be a net"

Tags: verilog

i wrote a truth table code in verilog and it show this error "varibale Y cannot be a net"
it is an equation to design a CMOS circuit it there any other way to declare the value of varibles instead of using the truth table? or is this method better if the error can be solved? this is the code down bellow

```
module pro1 ( A,B,C,D,E,Y); 
output Y ; 
 
input A,B,C,D,E ; 

assign Y = ~(A&B^C&D^A&E&D^C&E&B);


always @(A or B or C or D or E)
begin 
case ({A,B,C,D,E})

5'b00000:Y=0;
5'b00001:Y=0; 
5'b00010:Y=0; 
5'b00011:Y=0; 
5'b00100:Y=0; 
5'b00101:Y=0;
5'b00110:Y=1;
5'b00111:Y=1; 
5'b01000:Y=0; 
5'b01001:Y=0; 
5'b01010:Y=0; 
5'b01011:Y=0; 
5'b01100:Y=0;
5'b01101:Y=1;
5'b01110:Y=1;
5'b01111:Y=1;
5'b10000:Y=1;
5'b10001:Y=0;
5'b10010:Y=0;
5'b10011:Y=1;
5'b10100:Y=0;
5'b10101:Y=0;
5'b10110:Y=1;
5'b10111:Y=1;
5'b11000:Y=1;
5'b11001:Y=1;
5'b11010:Y=1;
5'b11011:Y=1;

    5'b11100:Y=1;
    5'b11101:Y=1;
    5'b11110:Y=1;
    5'b11111:Y=1;

endcase 
end
 
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

Verilog only allows continuous assignments to wires na d procedural assignments to variables. For simple combinational logic, the two following descriptions are identical in functionality.

```
module pro1 ( input wire A,B,C,D,E,
              output wire Y); 
  assign Y = ~(A&B^C&D^A&E&D^C&E&B);
endmodule


module pro1 ( input wire A,B,C,D,E,
              output reg Y); 
  always @(*)
    Y = ~(A&B^C&D^A&E&D^C&E&B);
endmodule
```

See https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/

Comment: thank you so much but how to declare the varibles 0 and 1 in this exampel?

Comment: I do not understand your question. 0 and 1 are numbers, not variables. You can use either the equation or the case statement, but not both.